# How to force Internet Explorer (IE) to REALLY reload the page?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, web-development

When using Internet Explorer 8 to test my web application I often find it doesn't reload the page, so I don't see my changes. This has resulted in a lot of wasted time and frustration wondering why my fix "didn't work" - when in fact the browser never loaded the fixed version.

I've tried the Refresh button. I've tried <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, holding <kbd>Control</kbd> while clicking the Refresh button, everything I could think of - it doesn't actually load the new contents from the server. I've confirmed this with Fiddler.

How do I tell IE "**I don't care what you think you have cached, I want to *reload* the page - no really, I *mean it* this time, honest-to-God, I want you to *actually* go to the server and download everything again**"?

Comment: Use a private browsing window, maybe?

Comment: Is it possible that your web server is serving the old page (via cache) instead of the new version? Doesn't matter how many times you reload in that case.

Comment: Michael, no, I verified in Fiddler that IE is not getting the page contents from the server.

Comment: Control+F5 goes past the Cache, it's odd if it doesn't....

Comment: Best wording of a question I have encountered so far on StackExchange!

Answer (score 130, accepted):

1. Select **Tools >> Internet Options**.
2. Click the **Settings** button in **Browsing History**.
3. Select the **Every time I visit the webpage** radio button.
4. Click **OK** to close the Settings dialog.
5. Click **OK** to close the Internet Options dialog.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing. I wonder if that hurts general browsing performance though. Also, if I ever need to get an end-user to do this it's not ideal (confusion, browser settings locked down, etc.). I'd love some simple way of doing a one-time reload, but I guess that doesn't exist in IE.

Comment: If this is what you did, mark it as the answer

Comment: It may hurt general browsing performance, but only if you do your general browsing with IE...

Comment: Ev: The user-facing side of this is usually fixed by changing the URLs for all scripts and stylesheets every time you touch the code, typically by adding a `?version-number` query string suffix.

Comment: "Every time I visit the webpage" likely doesn't do what you think it does. See http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf

Comment: I agree with @EricLaw, if you use Fiddler you will see that files associated with the page are sometimes not reloaded even when "Every time I visit the webpage" is set. Use the IE toolbar menu: Cache > Always refresh from server, or the Clear Cache button in Fiddler.

Comment: @PhillipNgan Unfortunately, "Always refresh from server" doesn't always work, either...

Answer (score 43):

Since it's stated that IE8 is the browser, you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the development tools and select the Cache menu at the top and then always refresh from server to bypass cache.

In short, **Press <kbd>F12</kbd>**.
Click **Cache** -> **Always Refresh from Server**

You can simply clear your cache here as well, if that is the desired action. The always refresh option is not a global option and will not hinder overall performance in IE.

IE7 also has development tools, but they must be installed separately. You can also use the IE8 dev tools to run the browser in IE7 mode.

Comment: +1 for solving this without using a global option.

Comment: Similar to [here](http://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page#comment118286_81183), that still doesn't always refresh all content.  And I don't know that that reload is good across URLs either -- each window seems to have its own F12 at times. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866619/how-to-force-ie-to-reload-javascript) is a more thorough way to do if, iff you have access to the javascript include.

Comment: How do you do this in IE 11? There's no cache option I can find.

Comment: In IE 11 this option is under F12 -> Network -> 3th icon from left.

Answer (score 22):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in IE reloads the page ignoring the cache

Comment: As it does in Firefox as well.

Comment: The OP says that doesn't work for him.  (Well, maybe he's wrong.)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I know it ignores the cache some of the time, but not all the time.

Comment: Ctrl+f5 always reloads the page from the server. What it doesn't necessarily do is reload the extra files that page references

Comment: Fair enough - but I need it to reload EVERYTHING.

Comment: CTRL+F5 should perform a full refresh of the page and all of its resources. Calls made via XMLHTTPRequest later might be cached (if you don't want them cached, send appropriate no-cache headers).

The one caveat is that if the page in question is XML, it's really being loaded via MSXML, and that DocHost does NOT respect CTRL+Refresh properly.

Comment: ctrl+f5 does not always reload everything from the server.   In my tests javascript contained in the html file do not reload after pressing ctrl-f5 even though the page has changed.

Answer (score 19):

IE is very eager to cache pages, even when you tell it not to via cache headers. [Microsoft KB 234067](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067/EN-US) explains the requisite incantations. In short, you need to deliver the following headers.

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: <some time in the past>
```

Setting `Expires = -1` (as recommended in the KB article) should work for most frameworks; browsers are required to treat invalid date formats as being in the past ([RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21)).

In .NET, you can do it on a page-by-page granularity by using this set of methods prior to calling the web page:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(System.Web.HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

see:
http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2012/10/force-a-page-refresh-on-a-asp-net-mvc-website/
Works well for MVC3.0.

Comment: Untrue. IE6+ fully respects all cache-prohibiting headers. http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf

Comment: That's all very well, but doesn't help WRT the question.

Answer (score 6):

The Network tab of the web developer toolbar has a button to easily clear the cache.  I usually use that in the case you describe.

It isn't ideal, since you may not really want to clear your entire cache, but since I don't use IE for general browsing, it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

This still happens in IE9. 
Amazingly, the answer is **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-Refresh button**

Comment: Does that function differently than Ctrl-Refresh button?

Answer (score 3):

Incidentally, the problem will possibly exist for your website viewers as well. I saw the following idea in an AJAX book...

Use PHP to add a random token to the current URL so that the browser is tricked into thinking it's a separate page.

Comment: Makes URLs ugly, though.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem myself. I believe the only way to do it is to clear the cache (Safety -> Delete Browsing History). Only check "Temporary Internet Files".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down either the <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key as you click refresh button.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may seem a bit odd... but one thing I've noticed lately, is that you do sometimes get different results depending on HOW you "refresh". I've seen the following behaviour:

<kbd>F5</kbd> > loads from cache without refresh,
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> > *really* refreshes bypassing the cache.
(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> can be replaced with clicking in the address bar)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that adding a random token to the url is the most reliable solution and once it's implemented the user doesn't have to do anything.

Aside from the random token approach what I tend to always do to force a complete reload (request) of the page and all of its dependant files I just place my cursor at the end of the url and press Enter.  Works every time... and I use IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F12</kbd> -> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is slightly faster for IE9+. As people have mentioned, IE doesn't clear the cache very intelligently like Chrome does.