# How to perform a Hard Refresh in Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am viewing a site on `localhost` in Edge.

All I want to do is fully refresh the page and all of its resources (external CSS, external JavaScript, images, fonts, everything that the page links to - I want to reload it all again from the server).

How can I do this?

---

This seems like a simple request, but this is what I have tried so far:

- F5
- CTRL + F5
- CTRL + SHIFT + F5
- SHIFT F5
- Clearing the Cache (Settings > Clear browsing data > ticked everything > Show more > ticked everything in there > Clear)
- Restarting Edge
- Restarting computer

None of this has worked. I have a change in a CSS file and a change in a JavaScript file. Every time old versions of those files are being loaded.

I just want to do a hard refresh and reload everything in Edge - what am I missing to achieve this?

---

This problem doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox (both show the latest content). [I basically want a solution like this](https://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page), but for Edge instead of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Edge is based on Internet Explorer this means, CTRL+F5 will peform a refresh of the cache content, if its not working then the reason the site isn't updating is unrelated to Edge.

Comment: according to this answer, CTRL+F5 is not enough to refresh cache content for IE: https://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page

Comment: I disagree with the accuracy of that answer.  It also doesn't matter.  You have also REMOVED your cache files, which still means, the reason it's not working is for a different reason.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both show the correct content. Only Edge shows the older files. This is an issue, was an issue with Internet Exporer, and is now an issue with Edge.

Comment: [This Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10607/microsoft-edge-view-delete-browser-history) may provide some useful information.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin unfortunately this page did not help.  Perhaps my problem is that my files are hosted on `localhost`

Comment: If explicitly clearing the cache per those instructions didn't do the trick, you may have some other issue. Are you loading the pages using the file: protocol or the http: or https: protocol?

Comment: using the http: protocol - please bear in mind that this issue is not present in Firefox or Chrome - only Edge is serving up old versions of these files

Comment: "This seems like a simple request" - No request is too simple for IE/Edge...

Comment: Anyone else seeing this page in IE Edge and having an awkward feeling? Even coming from bing. Shiver...

Comment: 07/2020 still not working (Edge 89 based on Chromium)... It only works in dev tools by checking Disable cache option.

Comment: Edge uses the Chromium engine with Blink and V8 engines, it is not based on IE.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[image: Cache control setting]

Thanks to @Jimmery I found a setting.

Tried Ctrl+R but it does not bypass cache

**Update (2022):**

In Chromium edge it is a checkbox

[image: Edge Dev Tools]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for local content, unfortunately

Comment: Sadly that button isn't in Edge any longer

Answer (score 10):

You need to Open Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) and when you right click the refresh button you have more refresh options like Ctrl+Shift+R to Reload the current page, ignoring cached content and another one to clear cache and refresh.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4531783/microsoft-edge-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

With Chromium-based Edge, it’s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I found for Edge only the answer from [Heriberto Diaz](https://superuser.com/a/1555464/505363) using Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution can help you (in any browser):
in your html header tag, append an extra value to your css or js file address! like this:
`<link href="yourCssFile.css?v=1"/>`
the "?v=1" cause that your browser redownload your css file.
hope it help you ;)

Comment: Welcome to Super User Ashkan! This might work in the case for a erver controlled by OP, but how do you propose modifying the header tags of an arbitrary web page?