# How to make microsoft edge load from cache

Tags: cache, microsoft-edge

Firefox has this wonderful add-on called load from cache you can get it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/load-from-cache/) I use this on android to save some bandwidth and also it's faster to press the back button and not have to reload the entire page while doing so.

I am looking for the same functionality in microsoft edge. Does anyone know a way of doing that?

Comment: See answer at https://superuser.com/a/1245169/274155